# How to enable non-3G data

Tags: data-connection

After I got my mighty [Fly-Ying FG8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg-pJq32R5Q) I didn't care for mobile data, mostly due to the measly 5MB data plan with extortionate overage charges. I miss the occasional emails on the road, Waze navigation and A-GPS so I thought to put these 5MB to good use.

The problem is that in the Settings => Mobile networkד I have only "data roaming", "Access Point Names" and "Network Operators" on both SIMs. I couldn't make the device use its EDGE capability. Does anyone know how to turn it on?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you have a non-3G data plan? If not why wouldn't you want to use the fster 3G?  Modern phones/networks only default to EDGE when there is no 3G connection.  It's not managed separately.

Comment: The phone doesn't support 3G. It's true, the question and the answer were "how to enable data" rather than "how to enable EDGE"

Comment: Ah, OK. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Appereantly, you have to define an "Access Point Name" in order for your mobile data to work.

in Settings => Wireless & networks => Mobile networks => Access Point Names => menu => New APN

The settings vary by operator, you can find the Israeli ones [here](http://www.iphoneblog.co.il/2011/05/apnmms.html).